# 'dict' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, mobile, automation, appium

I am new to web automation and python so please understand my problem may be trivial to you all. I am trying to use Appium to test an app and to press a button on the screen. Using my minimum knowledge i have I created a test case below that is meant to do that but I get an error 'dict' object has no attribute 'driver'

```
from appium import webdriver
import time

def setUp():
    self = dict(
        platformName = "Android",
        platformVersion = "10",
        deviceName= "name",
        app= "C:\\AppiumProjects\\app-debug.apk",
        automationName= "UiAutomator2",
        appActivity = ".activities.SplashScreenActivity",
        appPackage = 'genericsurveyapp2',
        noReset = True,
        
        )
        
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',self)
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    self.el = self.driver.find_element_by_id("idacceptButton")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.el.click

setUp()
```

Comment: Don't use dot (.) in variable declaration. Try this instead:  `self_driver = .........`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused by naming your dictionary of config options self.
When working in a class `self` allows you to reference variables and methods of the class using "dot notation". However with a dictionary "dot notation" lets you access variables and methods of the dictionary class, not the contents of the dictionary.

You basically have 3 options for how to solve this:

1. Add elements to the dictionary using dictionary notation. I wouldn't recommend this because you're storing 3 different types of things in the same dictionary, config options, the driver object, and a page element.

```py
self['driver'] = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',self)
self['el'] = self['driver'].find_element_by_id("idacceptButton")
self['el'].click()
```

2. Assign `driver` and `el` as variables in the local context of the function. If you intend to throw away the config, driver, and page element after setup, this is the solution I'd go with.

```py
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',self)
el = driver.find_element_by_id("idacceptButton")
el.click()
```

3. Refactor your code to use a class following the page object pattern. This is likely what you want to do since it aligns with appium testing best practices.